# Syntax error at or near /" while using lower()

Tags: postgresql

I am retrieving the following sql statement from a table and then using bind variables to substitute the values in. I get a syntax error when running the statement. It seems to be occurring as a result of the lower() function however I believe I am using this correctly. I have tried running the statement manually via psql and it works fine with the values I provide. Does anyone have any ideas on this one? I have tried switching the ' for $$ but this had no effect.

**statement**

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name=lower(':1') 
  and column_name=lower(':2')
```

**expected basic statement with substituted values**

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name=lower('MyTableName') 
  and column_name=lower('MyColumnName')
```

**statement run by postgresql**

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name=lower('((E'RWOL_TMA_ROADWORKS'))') 
and column_name=lower('((E'TPHS_CWAY_RESTRICT_TYPE'))')
```

**Error in C#**

```
ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near \"MyTableName\"
```

**Error in PostgreSQL log file**

```
2012-04-16 11:36:15 BST ERROR:  syntax error at or near "RWOL_TMA_ROADWORKS" at character 80
2012-04-16 11:36:15 BST STATEMENT:  SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name=lower('((E'RWOL_TMA_ROADWORKS'))') and column_name=lower('((E'TPHS_CWAY_RESTRICT_TYPE'))')
```

EDIT: Retrieval and implementation code is written in C#. I use the database connection base classes and the npgsql provider factory in order to make connections, run queries and retrieve the data. This method works for all other queries that use this method of binding variables etc apart from this one where I try to use the lower() function.

EDIT:  I have tried removing the quotes altogether to let the binding agent deal with quoting the values and this provided the same syntax error.

EDIT: Have now enabled logging and added the actual statement that postgresql is running.

Comment: What kind of bind variables you're using? `psql` ones? `plpgsql`? `java` maybe?

Comment: Have added an edit to OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think vyegorov is on the right path - there's something funny with your placeholders.

I don't think your second example is the actual query after substition because that doesn't contain any errors. Where did it come from and why aren't you providing the actual query - do you have statement logging turned on in PostgreSQL?

Also, I'm suspicious of the syntax error - what's going on with the escaped double-quotes? Are they actually double-quotes and not doubled-up single quotes?

1. Are you sure you need single-quotes around your placeholders? Usually the drivers manage that for you.
2. Are you sure you aren't double-quoting the values anywhere?

Get the actual SQL and look at the quoting and the problem will be obvious I suspect.

UPDATE: now have SQL

Here's the error in the posted statement:

```
lower('((E'RWOL_TMA_ROADWORKS'))')
```

You've got two levels of quotes here. Remove the ones you've added and we should end up with something like:

```
lower((E'RWOL_TMA_ROADWORKS'))
```

Ignoring the repeated brackets that's valid (The E'...' is the syntax for a c-style escaped string - google around standard_conforming_strings).

Comment: The single quotes are there because the lower() function uses the syntax: lower('yourtext'). I have not had any issues using single quotes on any of my other statements. The reason they are used is because I want the variables to be treated as literal strings. For example if I were to add a clause like this: where namecol = ghghg the query would fail. If I did where namecol = 'ghghg' the query would pass.

Comment: I have tried removing the quotes completely in order to let the binding agent deal with it but this produced the same syntax error.

Comment: But surely your db wrapper handles the quoting automatically for you? Or perhaps that's the problem and it's double-quoting because table_name is an identifier rather than text. Anyway - get the SQL and you'll know.

Comment: Any ideas on how to get the sql? I am unsure how to access the logs. Is there anything like the SQL Server trace tool? I have accessed the log file found here: C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.1\data\pg_log but there was no entry for the failed query.

Comment: I have now added the statement as found in the log file after I enabled logging.

Comment: You are correct. I removed the quotes on the wrong database. I have now removed them from the statements in the correct database and the wrapper class for the bind variables is now taking care of the quoting issue. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you shouldn't use quotes around `:1` and `:2`.  Most APIs that support bind variables will correctly quote the value for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is not `lower()` functions' issue, but rather bind variable processing issue.

As @Adrian suggests, try not to use quotes around your bind variables.
And you should also consult your databases logs, you'll see more information there about what's going on.

**EDIT:** Use:

```sql
SHOW data_directory;
SHOW log_directory;
```

`SQL` statement to find the locations of your DATA directory and logs location, if logs path is relative, then it will be relative to the DATA directory.

Go there and find the recently modified file, check the contents. You should see the error message with default PostgreSQL configuration.

And it'd be good for you to enable debugging also on the middleware / factory levels.

Comment: How do you access the logs in postgresql. I am very new to it so have no idea. That is the reason I cannot post the query that postgresql receives and can only post the query c# side.